How typescript array typing
I found a typescript task: return the first element of the array:
type First<T extends unknown[]> = T[0]
let first: First<[1,2,3]>

I decided to redo it a bit so that we can set which element we need.:
const arr = [1,'2',4]

type El<T extends unknown[], N extends number> = T['length'] extends 0? never : T[N]

let el1:El<[1,'2',4],2> //4

let el2: El<typeof arr,2> // 4 , but I see string | number

let el3: El<arr,2> // 4, but I see error


How to return never if there is no such element (the array is shorter)?
Why el2 is string | number and not number or 4?
Why el3 is error


Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

There is a difference between a Tuple type and an Array type.
When defining an array as const arr = [1,'2',4], you define an array with the type (string | number)[].
If you want to use as a tuple you can use as const.
const arr = [1,'2',4] as const // Type: readonly [1, "2", 4]


An array doesn't know the length it has. Only that it is a list of a certain type. string | number in the case of arr. You have to define as a tuple type to be able to check the length.

All elements of the array are of type string | number

arr is a value and not a type. You first have to get the type of arr with typeof.


typeof arr

